# Convert array to matrix in C

Tags: c, arrays, matrix

I have a homework where i have to convert an array to a matrix. I already have a working solution, however since I didn't use the size parameter I removed it from the function declaration (and the tests), but my teacher did **not** like that. So now I would need help to figure out how size is supposed to be used here.

My function (with all parameters) looks like this:

```c
static void array_to_matrix(int n_rows, int n_cols, cell_t matrix[][n_cols], const cell_t arr[], int size) {
    int i = 0;
    for (int r = 0; r < n_rows; r++) {
        for (int c = 0; c < n_cols; c++) {
            matrix[r][c] = arr[i++];
        }
    }
}
```

And the tests that my teacher has made looks like this:

```c
#define ARR_EQUALS(v1, v2) printf( memcmp(v1, v2, sizeof(v1)) == 0 ? "true\n" : "false\n")

...

void test_array_to_matrix() {
    cell_t cells1[4];
    get_cells(cells1, 4, 0.5);
    cell_t world1[2][2];
    array_to_matrix(2, 2, world1, cells1, 4);

    int expected1[] = {1, 1};
    ARR_EQUALS(world1[0], expected1); // First row


    // Test a bigger one
    cell_t cells2[9];
    get_cells(cells2, 9, 0.5);
    cell_t world2[3][3];
    array_to_matrix(3, 3, world2, cells2, 9);
    int expected3[] = {1, 1, 0};
    ARR_EQUALS(world2[1], expected3); // Mid row
}
```

Comment: It doesn't make much sense to pass `n_rows`, `n_cols` and `size`. To me it seems that all you can do is a sanity check like: `assert(n_rows * n_cols == size);`

Comment: Exactly. Maybe I should just hand it in with the unused variable still there. It doesn't seem like he cares about warnings anyway, based on his own code

Comment: You can suppress warning by adding `(void)size;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it is guaranteed that size will be equal to n_rows*n_cols, then the size parameter is not used logically as it behaves just as a derived variable.
However, your teacher most probably will not want to modify his/her tests code just to test your solution, that's why you have to follow the declaration he/she has given you which includes the size parameter. 
The test code knows that it will call `array_to_matrix(int n_rows, int n_cols, cell_t matrix[][n_cols], const cell_t arr[], int size)`. But if you change it, then the existing test code will not work and will need to modify.

What we learn from here is that, we have to work in a team. Just because you can omit something, you shouldn't do it because you already agreed on an API declaration that is going to be used by others. Imaging joining a server team and you suddenly change the definition of an API, thousands of clients are going to suffer for it.

Comment: That's reasonable I guess, but it doesn't really make much sense when he has written a comment saying "assume n_rows * n_cols == size and matrix square"

Comment: Maybe in the future, there may come some new feature that will require this variable. Don't think of it for just this problem.